# Volume Snapshot Service - ignore FilesNotToSnapshot

Tags: c++, windows, volume-shadow-service

I'm using `Volume Snapshot Services` (VSS) to backup a drive. By default all files listed under `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\BackupRestore\FilesNotToSnapshot` are deleted from the snapshot by VSS.

How can I make VSS to keep those files? There is some software (for ex. Macrium Reflect) that is able to do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On systems that have it (XP doesn't), the "Shadow copy optimization writer" is the one in charge of deleting unwanted files from the shadow copy after the snapshot is taken.

I would either try to explicitely disable this writer, or call SetContext() with the VSS_VOLSNAP_ATTR_NO_AUTORECOVERY flag (it should prevent any post-snapshot write operation). However MSDN says that [this flag has drawbacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately that flag disables all writers, which is not what I want. I only need to ignore FilesNotToSnapshot. Macrium apparently does that by adding only necessary backup components rather than using default backup component list

Comment: And only disabling the "shadow copy optimization writer" as I suggested? Maybe it's worth trying

Comment: Good idea, sorry I missed it. Do you by any chance know how to do it?

Comment: Probably using [DisableWriterClasses()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382657(v=vs.85).aspx) or DisableWriterInstances()

Comment: @Isso, So how was it?

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot @mbarthelemy and sorry I forgot to mark the answer. Will do in a sec